# Why LAPACKE_dsygvd returns error after changing size of matrix?

Tags: c++, lapack, intel-mkl

I am trying to solve the generalized eigenvalue problem for the hydrogen atom by using LAPACKE_dsygvd. For the parameters of the generator functions, I use an interval that starts at 0.01 and takes N steps of 0.01. What I change is the value of N. Everythings fine for N = 14 and below, where I get the answers from the analytical solution. However, when I choose N = 15 and above, I get an error and info is returned with a value > N. After reading the documentation from LAPACK, it says the following:

> N:   if INFO = N + i, for 1 <= i <= N, then the leading
>                       minor of order i of B is not positive definite.
>                       The factorization of B could not be completed and
>                       no eigenvalues or eigenvectors were computed.

But I have checked my matrix B and it is positive definite. I don't know what is wrong.

Below I show my scripts

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "library.h"
#include "mkl.h"

using namespace std;

double Superposition(const double ai, const double aj, const int m);

double Hamiltonian(const double ai, const double aj, const int m);

void print_matrix(double *A, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            printf("%.7f ", A[i*n + j]);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}

void print_vector(double *vec, int n) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << vec[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

double* interval(double min, double step) {
    double *result;
    result = (double *)mkl_malloc( N*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        result[i] = min + i*step;
    }
    return result;
}   
int main() {
    cout << Ry << "\n";
    double *S, *H, *I, *eigenvalues;
    double alpha, beta;
    int i, j, info;

    char* uplo = "U"; char* jobz = "V";

    I = interval(0.01, 0.01);

    alpha = 1.0; beta = 0.0;

    S = (double *)mkl_malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    H = (double *)mkl_malloc( N*N*sizeof( double ), 64 );
    eigenvalues = (double *)mkl_malloc( N*sizeof( double ), 64 );

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int index = i*N + j;
            if (j < i) {
                S[index] = 0.0;
                H[index] = 0.0;
            }
            else {
                S[index] = Superposition(I[i], I[j], m);
                H[index] = Hamiltonian(I[i], I[j], m);
            }
        }
    }

    print_matrix(S, N); cout << "\n";
    print_matrix(H, N); cout << "\n" << "\n";

    info = LAPACKE_dsygv(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, 1, *jobz, *uplo, N,
        H, N, S, N, eigenvalues);

    //print_matrix(H, N); cout << "\n";

    //for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    //  eigenvalues[i] /= Ry;
    //}
    cout << info << "\n" << "\n";
    print_matrix(H, N); cout << "\n";
    print_vector(eigenvalues, N);

    mkl_free(S);
    mkl_free(H);
    mkl_free(I);
    mkl_free(eigenvalues);
}
```

*Edit: I used dsygvd as included in MKL, and the same error doesn't occur. However, I get very different results for both functions using the same inputs.

Comment: What is the  defference you obtained with dsyevd and dsyev routines are used?

Comment: How could I build your example to check the problem on my part? I am not aware of double Superposition(..)  and Hamiltonian(...);